# How do you play a slur for the same note?

Tags: piano, slurs

I am learning a new piece on piano and there's a slur between the same note like this:

[image: notes]

Am I supposed to strike the key twice and use the sustain pedal in between?

Comment: When it's the same note it's a. **tie**, not a slur. Just hold the note for the duration of both notes.

Comment: @Pete_Becker Please post answers as answers (not as comments).

Answer (score 0):

A slur to the same note is called a 'tie'.   Play it as one extended note.

Comment: Technically slurs and ties are two different things and should look slightly different. Also there is a lot of wind and brass music with slurs over repeated notes, so the question of what to do when you see a slur over repeated notes is still valid. I agree that the image in question looks like a tie, not a slur.

Comment: Might be worth explaining the "why": in this 2-beat time signature, it's the only way to get a 4-beat note.

Comment: Just give the OP a simple answer.  This question will be taken down as a duplicate pretty soon anyway.